# (onError): The error handler of Future.catchError must return a value of the future's type)

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

here is my code, what i want to achieve is to show a snackbar to a user with the error which works fine but then the error is not caught and the app gets hanged ...

```
void signUp(String email, String password) async {
if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
  try {
    await _auth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
        .then((value) => {postDetailsToFirestore()})
        .catchError((e) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: e!.message);

    });
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
    switch (error.code) {
      case "invalid-email":
        errorMessage = "Your email address appears to be malformed.";
        break;
      case "wrong-password":
        errorMessage = "Your password is wrong.";
        break;
      case "user-not-found":
        errorMessage = "User with this email doesn't exist.";
        break;
      case "user-disabled":
        errorMessage = "User with this email has been disabled.";
        break;
      case "too-many-requests":
        errorMessage = "Too many requests";
        break;
      case "operation-not-allowed":
        errorMessage = "Signing in with Email and Password is not enabled.";
        break;
      default:
        errorMessage = "An undefined Error happened.";
    }
    
    // default snackbar
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: errorMessage!);
    print(error.code);
    // custom snackbar
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
    ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
    ..showSnackBar(getSnack( errorMessage!, ContentType.failure, 'Failed !'));
    
    }
  }
}
```

now the problem is that it works fine when a new user creates an account but this error don't get caught when the user registers with the same email twice ... tried a lot of things like returning future and formatting and on error instead of catch error but i'm stuck on it for hours ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case that you need to check is `email-already-in-use` and it should catch it when registering for a user using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method. You can check for other error codes in the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/createUserWithEmailAndPassword.html).

Also, if you're using `async/await` in your code, it's unnecessary to use `then().catchError()` in this case. You are fine just doing

```dart
try {
    await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    postDetailsToFirestore();
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
  // handle error
}
```

Comment: tried both of your suggestions they works wonders, you are a saver !!